# Environment variables with Supervisor

Tags: django, deployment, environment-variables, supervisord

I've setup supervisor to run celeryd, celerycam and gunicorn as per [this blogpost](http://apreche.net/complete-single-server-django-stack-tutorial/). Everything ran smoothly at first. After the first restart, nothing started up. The logs I can see are of the form.

> Unknown command: 'run_gunicorn'
>
> Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

I'm guessing this is because supervisor doesn't 'see' my environment variables like DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE, DB_HOST, etc. I put all of them in /etc/environment but it's of no use. Again, I tried putting them against `environment` tag in /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf under `[supervisor]`. I'm getting the following error

> Starting supervisor: Error: Format string '\'DEBUG\'="False",
>   \'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE\'="project.settings.production",for
>   'environment' is badly formatted

My supervisord.conf has the following contents under [supervisord]

```
[supervisord]
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log ; (main log file;default $CWD/supervisord.log)
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid ; (supervisord pidfile;default supervisord.pid)
childlogdir=/var/log/supervisor            ; ('AUTO' child log dir, default $TEMP)

; the below section must remain in the config file for RPC
; (supervisorctl/web interface) to work, additional interfaces may be
; added by defining them in separate rpcinterface: sections
environment = 'DEBUG'="False",'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'="project.settings.production",
```

[Update - Adding logs from celery, gunicorn, celerycam]

Logs from celeryd_err.log

> ImportError: No module named debug_toolbar
>
> ImportError: No module named debug_toolbar
>
> ImportError: No module named debug_toolbar

Logs from celerycam_err.log

> ImportError: No module named debug_toolbar
>
> ImportError: No module named debug_toolbar
>
> ImportError: No module named debug_toolbar

Logs from gunicorn_err.log

> Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
>
> Unknown command: 'run_gunicorn'
>
> Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
>
> Unknown command: 'run_gunicorn'
>
> Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
>
> Unknown command: 'run_gunicorn'

Any suggestions to where I can get the solution? Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: what is the directory structure of your `settings` module ?

Comment: Are you sure you're still IN your environment when you try to start the server?

Comment: @J.Ghyllebert I'm actually not using a virtual env in this server. This server is going to be dedicated for this project alone.

Comment: @karthikr I'm using the [twoscoops-of-django](https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project) template for this project.

Comment: If you need to look at my celeryd.conf and other conf files, please drop a word here.

Comment: i asked for the directory structure, not the template language. Do you have an `__init__.py` in settings folder ?

Comment: @karthikr that twoscoops link points to a _project_ template.

Comment: [link to settings folder](https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project/tree/develop/project_name/project_name/settings) in that project template

Answer (score 4):

It's probably more appropriate to edit your gunicorn.conf file.

It should look something like:

```
[program:gunicorn]
...
environment=DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE='project.settings.production',DEBUG='False'
```

Note that there isn't a trailing comma, the 'keys' are not quoted and the values are quoted. While quotes aren't necessary if you're using just alphanumeric values, it's safer just to do this.

To ensure that your configuration files are good in supervisor, do the following:

```
sudo supervisorctl
reread
```

Deal with any errors that may be output.

I found that it was necessary to reload supervisor to get the configuration files to take effect:

```
sudo supervisorctl
reload
```